Unable to start liferay server 7.4
I am using Liferay Portal 7.4 Community version with OpenJDK11. When I start the server, I am getting the given exceptions in the console with a fail startup. Its a fresh Liferay vanilla version and no custom modules are deployed.

2024-06-19 05:28:19.858 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: ef6a5f94-965b-4fdf-a282-fa7f927f3030][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\pankaj.fathesingh\Softwares\LiferayPortal\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\632\0\.cp\lib\stax2-api.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipFile(ZipBundleFile.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.lockOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.loadManifest(ClasspathEntry.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.<init>(ClasspathEntry.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createClassPathEntry(ModuleClassLoader.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.createClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.getClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addStandardClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.buildClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.<init>(ClasspathManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader.<init>(EquinoxClassLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.createClassLoaderPrivledged(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.getModuleClassLoader(BundleLoader.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.getClassLoader(BundleLoader.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleWiring.getClassLoader(ModuleWiring.java:257)
    at com.liferay.portal.classloader.tracker.internal.ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator$1.addingBundle(ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator.java:43)
    at com.liferay.portal.classloader.tracker.internal.ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator$1.addingBundle(ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator.java:35)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 55)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.checkExtraFields(ZipFile.java:1274)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1734)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1463)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:742)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:257)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:304)
    ... 42 more
2024-06-19 05:28:19.887 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: ef6a5f94-965b-4fdf-a282-fa7f927f3030][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\pankaj.fathesingh\Softwares\LiferayPortal\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\632\0\.cp\lib\woodstox-core.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipFile(ZipBundleFile.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.lockOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.loadManifest(ClasspathEntry.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.<init>(ClasspathEntry.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createClassPathEntry(ModuleClassLoader.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.createClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.getClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addStandardClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.buildClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.<init>(ClasspathManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader.<init>(EquinoxClassLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.createClassLoaderPrivledged(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.getModuleClassLoader(BundleLoader.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.getClassLoader(BundleLoader.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleWiring.getClassLoader(ModuleWiring.java:257)
    at com.liferay.portal.classloader.tracker.internal.ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator$1.addingBundle(ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator.java:43)
    at com.liferay.portal.classloader.tracker.internal.ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator$1.addingBundle(ClassLoaderTrackerBundleActivator.java:35)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 55)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.checkExtraFields(ZipFile.java:1274)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1734)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1463)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:742)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:257)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:304)
    ... 42 more
2024-06-19 05:28:19.896 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: ef6a5f94-965b-4fdf-a282-fa7f927f3030][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\pankaj.fathesingh\Softwares\LiferayPortal\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\632\0\.cp\lib\xmlschema-core.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipFile(ZipBundleFile.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.lockOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.loadManifest(ClasspathEntry.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathEntry.<init>(ClasspathEntry.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createClassPathEntry(ModuleClassLoader.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.createClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.getClasspath(ClasspathManager.java:292)



I have tried deleting the state and temp folders but still it didn't help.

The key error is on the second line of your log: "Error opening zip file", and the Caused by is "Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 55)". Can you please check the file at the path in the second line? Is it corrupt? Does it match a stax2-api.jar you've got somewhere in the liferay distribution, or from somewhere else? Can you open it with other zip tools or other versions of jar? etc.

This is a well known issue, documented here.
From the resolution there:

If you use Windows, set the -Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true JVM parameter in your /bin/setenv.bat file.

If you use Linux, set the same parameter in the setenv.sh file

If you use Docker:

Using docker run, set the -e LIFERAY_JVM_OPTS=-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true variable

Using docker with compose.yaml, set the below in it:
  liferay:
      image: liferay/dxp:7.4.13.nightly
      environment:
        LIFERAY_JVM_OPTS: "-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true"



Additional Information
This error is due to the latest change in JDK 11.0.20(Release Note)

   core-libs/java.util.jar
   ➜ Improved ZIP64 Extra Field Validation(JDK-8302483 (not public))

java.util.zip.ZipFile has been updated to provide additional validation of ZIP64 extra fields when opening a ZIP file. This validation may be disabled by setting the system property jdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation to true


I have added this property in my setenv set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true" but still getting this sisue: Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 55
